# Why regular expression pattern does not match only in Python?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I tested the pattern on notepad++ and python regular expression test web sites and it works great. But in python it does not match. ***regex.search*** method returns None.

**Text**:

```
├¢  Downloads      : 20314 times                                      
├¢  Language       : English                                       
├¢  Format         : srt                                           
├¢  Total          : 1 subtitle file
```

**Pattern**:

```
^.{1,3}\s+(.*?):\s+(.*?)$
```

**Script**:

```
 with open('file.txt','r',encoding='utf-8') as f:
        string = f.read()
        print(string)
        pattern = r'^.{1,3}\s+(.*?):\s+(.*?)$'
        regex = re.compile(pattern)
        match = regex.search(string,re.UNICODE|re.M)
        print( 'Matching "%s"' % pattern)
        print ('  ', match.group())
        print ('  ', match.groupdict())
```

Comment: can't able to reproduce, works for me.

Comment: What version of Python?

Comment: I consider myself pretty good at regex, but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the purpose of `(.*?)`

Comment: @user590028, the added `?` makes the search expression lazy.  For an explanation, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions

Comment: @user590028 The first group in pattern is a key, and the second group in pattern is a value. I am trying to figure key/value pairs out in regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply the flags in `re.compile()` function not in search :

```
>>> regex = re.compile(pattern,re.U|re.M)
>>> regex.search(st)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f367951b2d8>
>>> regex.search(st).group()
u'\u251c\xa2  Downloads      : 20314 times
```

If you apply the flags in `re.search` it will returns None :

```
>>> regex = re.compile(pattern)
>>> regex.search(st,re.U|re.M).group()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```